# What is the reason behind Object Type having methods like ToString(),GetHashCode(),GetType etc

Tags: c#, .net

I have a question which might look silly. Is there any specific reason behind defining methods like ToStrin(),GetHashCode(),GetType() etc on the base Object Type . Are these methods internally be used by the .Net framework for any purpose. Just curious to know the thoughts that have been behind this design.

Thanks,
sveerap

Comment: Where else would you put them?

Comment: @Anon In an interface? Question with relevant answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561617/edited-why-does-object-tostring-exist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These methods were considered the bare minimum required by all objects.  By introducing them to the `System.Object` class, they are available on all objects within .NET.

Each serves a purpose:

- `Equals` and `ReferenceEquals` are used for equality checking
- `GetHashCode` allows objects to be used in hashed collections
- `GetType` is required for reflection to work
- `ToString` allows all objects, regardless of type, to be represented in a string form, which is incredibly useful
- `Finalize` allows resources to be handled properly by the garbage collector
- `MemberwiseClone` allows for shallow copies of objects to be generated

Comment: Thanks for the response and it covers most of the basic methods and reasons. On the string Brennan and PandaWood gave more detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

- GetType() is used for reflection
- GetHashCode() is used for object comparison

Comment: Thanks for the response. It would have been good if I can vote multiple answers as everybody shared useful views.

Comment: GetHashCode() is not used for object comparison though it has contract that equal objects have equal hash codes.

Answer (score 0):

The main .NET languages don't have duck typing, so even if two different classes T1 and T2 had methods called "ToString", you would not be able to write code that can act on an object of either type T1 or T2. That's why methods that are commonly used by polymorphic code are declared in Object. And since the methods you mentioned make sense for almost all classes, this can't really do harm.

**Edit:** Actually, C# does support duck typing in its latest incarnation. But that incurs reflection overhead, and also ToString and company were defined long before anyone had ever thought of making C# duck-typing-friendly.

Comment: In C# 4.0 it supports duck typing with the dynamic keyword.. ie: private void test (dynamic test)
{
 test.someMethod(); 
}

Comment: Right. Wasn't thinking of that -- I've only used 3.0 and below. Editing answer to address.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It would have been good if I can vote multiple answers as everybody shared useful views.