# How ToString(), GetHashCode() methods appear for each object in C#

Tags: c#

For a class, ClassA, how does the object contain ToString(), GetHashCode(), GetType() methods by default.

And if ChildClassA is inherited from ClassA, how does GetType() on base and child object gives its own implementation result.

Is there any magic behind it.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622068/what-is-the-reason-behind-object-type-having-methods-like-tostring-gethashcode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All classes that are not derived from some other explicitly stated class derive from `object`, that has the three methods you are asking about. And yes, there is some magic behind `.GetType()`, it is defined as

```
[Pure]
[ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
public extern Type GetType();
```

So the .net runtime has special native code to handle it.

Answer (score 2):

Any class in .NET is inherited from `object`. Either directly, because that's the default when you create a type or indirectly because you inherit from another type that itself inherited object.

The methods `ToString()`, `GetHashCode()`and `GetType()`are defined and implemented for `object` so any other type inherits them. They are `virtual` so any other derived type can `override` them and use it's own implementation if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Previous answers are great. I just want to explain default implementation a bit

**GetType().** When some class is compiled by JIT compiler (e.g. `System.String`, `ClassA`, etc) an internal CLR structure inherited from `System.Type` is created in memory. We call it type-object. It describes a type (its name, fields, methods, properties, base class, interfaces etc). And GetType() just returns this type-object for class.

```
var a = new ClassA();
var type = a.GetType(); // will return type object that describes ClassA
```

**ToString().** Basically it is a virtual method that looks like

```
public virtual string ToString()
{
    return GetType().FullName;
}
```

**GetHashCode().** This is also a virtual method that generates reliable hash codes. Digging further there are 3 default hashing algorithms: for reference types, for value types or structs that contain only value types (fast), for structs that contain reference types (slow). Since with `GetType()` CLR can get type of object, it's easy to pick an appropriate hashing algorithm.

So as you can see there is no magic at all